# Newest Lenovo legion Y540 wifi adapter not found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wireless, lenovo

I'v been struggling with the wifi adapter problem for my legion Y540 on the ubuntu 18.04 system. I have tried a lot solutions but none is working.

The output of lshw -C Network

```
 *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:c2498000-c249bfff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: enp7s0
       version: 15
       serial: 54:05:db:f8:4f:15
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=10.128.96.12 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:c2204000-c2204fff memory:c2200000-c2203fff
```

Does anyone know how to solve the problem? Please help me about this. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you're using the newest hardware, try the newest software as well. Use a live usb stick with Ubuntu 20.10. Does it work now? You're realtek ethernet should be working though- it is old hardware....

Comment: So you are expecting a 3+ year old kernel to know in advance about your WiFi adapter from some weeks ago and to have a driver for it? Simply use a recent Ubuntu, and it will probably work out of the box.

Comment: Does the driver manager offer the backport-intel-dkms?